# Rails - mixing of 'send' and 'try'

Tags: ruby-on-rails, dynamic, attributes

I have an object which could be nil. In the next line i am getting any one of the object's argument dynamically based on some condition. I was using object.try() with if else block. Now I want to use send() so that I can achieve some efficient code.

```
form_name = 'parent' ( received from argument )
mes_record = Mark.first ( this can be nil )

if x == condition_1
    mes_record.parent
elsif x == condition_2
    mes_record.brother
elsif x == condition_3
    mes_record.sister
else
    mes_record.father
end
```

Now I want to avoid the if else ladder and use send.

```
 if mes_record.present?
      mes_record.send("#{form}")
 else
      mes_record = 'not available'
 end
```

I am searching for something like try.

```
   mes_record.try("dynamically substitute the attribute name here.") || 'not available'
```

Any help?!

Comment: Where is loop in your given code ?

Comment: It is not loop. If else block. Edited my question. Thanks!

Answer (score 9, accepted):

After trying for one hour i figured out the solution.

Hats off to Rails try method.

mes_record.try(:send, "#{form}") || 'not available'

Comment: Cool. It save a lot of times for me to find. Thank you.

Comment: This is redundant; `try` does the same thing as `send`, it just won't raise an exception. You should either only use try or use safe nav (&) before a call to send, though in general the OP's approach here is poor practice and indicative of code smell.

Answer (score 7):

A bit cleaner way is simply:

```
  mes_record.try(form.to_sym) || 'not available'
```

Comment: Yea, this seems the only way to do this. Also, not sure if the `to_sym` is necessary.